# Hide show/hide button in source list ( a view based outline view)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

[image]

how to hide show /hide button (edited as expand here). even i set it as empty string ,the border for the data cell shrinks as shown in image. previously  i used the method `- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:(id)item` , it hiding the show/hide string and working perfectly. but the problem is the outlineview allows only expanding not collapsing. i want to expand only one parent at a time by clicking the corresponding parent node.

Comment: fixed: [this code helped me](https://code.google.com/p/sequel-pro/source/browse/trunk/Source/SPFavoritesOutlineView.m?spec=svn4025&r=4025)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it, [this code](https://code.google.com/p/sequel-pro/source/browse/trunk/Source/SPFavoritesOutlineView.m?spec=svn4025&r=4025) helped me.

```
- (NSRect)frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    NSRect superFrame = [super frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:rowIndex];

    // Return NSZeroRect if the row is a group row
    if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(outlineView:isGroupItem:)]) {
        if ([[self delegate] outlineView:self isGroupItem:[self itemAtRow:rowIndex]]) {
            return NSZeroRect;
        }
    }


    return superFrame;
}
```

Comment: I have provided a better solution for you using another delegate method. Otherwise your solution could break at any moment, for example if clipping stops hiding the cells for you.

Answer (score 10):

Use this method from NSOutlineViewDelegate method :

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:(id)item;
```